# What is this cut of meat?

Tags: beef

These two Chinese recipes call for what they call a beef shank (https://youtu.be/esz2fBMGkPE?t=7 https://youtu.be/318rdUn5uq0?t=12), but the butchers I've asked about beef shanks direct me to cross cut, bone-in cuts like this: https://www.seriouseats.com/images/2015/01/20150118-braised-beef-shanks-daniel-gritzer01.jpg.

If I wanted to request the boneless shank referenced in these video recipes, what should I ask for in an American butcher shop?

Comment: Looks like a whole shin to me ... but they don't typically butcher cows that way in the US.  I thought there was a question or two on here about beef cuts, but well ... let's just say it's a matter of where you are.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cuts_of_beef